# How to decode Json data in javascript in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, decode

I have problem related to JSON. I have following code:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "100",
      "course_id": "92",
      "skills": "2",
      "from_time": "1:00am",
      "to_time": "5:30am",
      "class_type": "1",
      "no_weeks": "5",
      "cid": "16",
      "mon": "1",
      "tue": "1",
      "wed": "1",
      "thu": "0",
      "fri": "0",
      "sat": "0",
      "sun": "0",
      "intake": "30",
      "address": "raviwar peth",
      "payment": "3000",
      "payment_type": "per class",
      "payment_policy": "before lessons(monthly)",
      "cancellation_policy": "dfs  dfd sfds fsdf sd",
      "created_on": "2016-01-13 06:17:08"
    }
  ]
]
```

I can not decode this JSON data into JavaScript.

Comment: please add ajax php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have decode your json data.Please check [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2qbs0w2d/)

It might be issue in 0 append to json data.

Please check have you added `exit or die()`? If not please add after return json data in **ajax php** file.

Comment: Please check demo link .I have alert your single json data.. Hope you get your answer..thx @vinayak

Comment: can you tell me how I can print array data from ajax to html

Comment: It depends on where you want to display that data. :) @vinayak

Answer (score 1):

First create a `var text = '{"id":100,"count":1}'`.

After that use JavaScript `function JSON.parse(text)`

which is used to convert a JSON text into a JavaScript object:

```
obj = JSON.parse(text);

alert (obj.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this data is in a variable called `data`.

To parse it in Javascript use the code.

```
JSON.parse(data)
```